# SocketScan API Xamarin.Foms

Tags: xamarin.forms, portable-class-library

I need an example of using the socketscan API in a Xamarin Forms app.
In their example app they have a helper that relies on platform specific code and the views in Xamarin Forms apps are generally in the PCL.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Generally, you need to show more effort in your question. ["What have you tried?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/650012) For this specific example, I would start looking at the [Xamarin.Forms Quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) where you get a working example of how to incorporate platform-specific code in your *Xamarin.Forms* project.

Comment: Use [DependencyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/) to access platform specific code from a Forms PCL